# Make a feed like the facebook

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying make a feed like the facebook, but with links... I got the table **links**:

```
id, title, photo, etc...
```

Where the **pages** publish links.

But I got the table **shares**, where the **users** *share* links of **pages**:

```
id, user_id, link_id, etc...
```

And I got the table **followers**, that got:

```
id, user_id, follower_id, type
```

> (type = if follow user, or page, (user = 0, page = 1, group = 2))
>
> "I use the user_id to put the id of pages and groups too"

Now, I want to show random "published links (pages), shared links (users), shared links (by users in groups), between today and yesterday ordering by date desc...

> If the type = 0, return the view "user_share", if type = 1 return view
>   "page_link", etc...

I'm beginner, so I need your help to make it. This is my first project with Laravel, I'm want to learn.

Comment: what is the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

If You are looking for making facebook feed like via graph APIs ,Facebook removed this feature permanently you can only do with page access tokens and only pages can like the post of any other pages.

will give you error
`"message": "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens"`

You can read  updated docs & changelog here :
[object likes reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes)  and
[change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog)

hope this will help you.